# how to parsing SOAP Response in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I just started with web service using `SOAP`.

I using below code to get response.

```
$response  = $objClient->__getLastResponse();
```

My response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
         <ns1:getHotelValuedAvail xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:ns1="http://axis.frontend.hydra.hotelbeds.com">
             <HotelValuedAvailRS xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" timeToExpiration="1771163" totalItems="387" echoToken="DummyEchoToken">
                 <PaginationData currentPage="1" totalPages="387"/>
                 <ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="ngQXOz+UOoLDtPieFMhu9wdw">
                    <DateFrom date="20130709"/>
                    <DateTo date="20130711"/>
                    <Currency code="EUR">Euro</Currency>
                    <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
                        <Code>99361</Code>
                        <Name>Hilton Sa Torre Mallorca Resort</Name>
                        <Position latitude="39.42761529999999936535" longitude="2.75602390000000019299"/>
                    </HotelInfo>
                 </ServiceHotel>
             </HotelValuedAvailRS>
         </ns1:getHotelValuedAvail>
      </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can some one help me to get the value of Name Element?
I have tried `simplexml_load_string($response)` and and `X-Path("/Name")`, but i could not get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) :

You can try like this:

```
$response  = $objClient->__getLastResponse();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($response);
$names= $doc->getElementsByTagName( "Name" );
$name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
var_export( $name );
```

Comment: It return Null Value. But when i var_dump($doc); i can see the Node in the Insplect Element in Chrome. [Here is my testing site](http://daunpenh.allalla.com/test.php)

Comment: I parsed your xml via a file `    
$response  = file_get_contents("soap.xml");` instead of `$response  = $objClient->__getLastResponse();` . It parses the `Name` element.